Loop and store muliple paths Pandas
Goal: Parameterize multiple paths and merge all data on ID using pandas. For example, I have multiple paths below:

\Users\Documents\202301\data01.pqt
\Users\Documents\202302\data02.pqt
\Users\Documents\202303\data03.pqt
.
.
.
\Users\Documents{year}{month}\data{month}.pqt

I have no problems with parametrizing and merging the data but would like to know if there is a way to do a for loop on these files months/years at once and store/read/merge all parquet files within the loop.
I took a long route by storing and reading each file for once which takes a lot of manual work. Looking to automate this process and eliminate the need to create new code for each new file by using a for loop on the year and month within the file name.

You can use the glob library to do so.
from glob import glob

files = glob(r"\Users\Documents\*\*.pqt")

for file in files:
    pqt_df = pd.read_parquet(file)

files will be a list of all paths for your parquet files, which you'll iterate through

You can use Pathlib glob:
from pathlib import Path      
import pandas as pd


df = pd.concat(objs=[pd.read_parquet(path=file) for file in Path("C:/Users/Documents/").glob(pattern="*/data*.pqt")], ignore_index=True)

